# next.js fetch data from Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios, next.js, fetch-api

i am writing a simple user register using Laravel with a simple code

```
public function register()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', 'password']));
    
    auth()->login($user);

    return [
        'status' => true,
        'user' => $user
    ];
}
```

then i am sending the data form  `Next.Js` :

using `axios`:

```
let config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `http://localhost:8000/api/register`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: values,
}
axios(config)
.then(json => console.log(json))
```

it's work fine, but i send an used email address, it will through 422 code, and axios can't catch the result

using `fetch`:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/register', {
    method: "post",
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: new URLSearchParams(data)
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
```

also work but when use used email, it will send 302 code , and call the index `/`

Comment: _"it will through 422 code, and axios can't catch the result"_ - why don't you add a `.catch(...)` to the axios promise chain?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have missed adding the `.catch(...)` to return the error object like the example in docs
[Axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)